# Are these vowels?

Tags: hebrew, vowels-nekudot

I know the hebrew vowels. However, I recently came across this word: כְּשֶׁעָמְ֒דָה. What are the three dots above the מ?

Another example:  עַמְּ֒ךָ

In the same paragraph, I had  וְהִדְלִֽיקוּ. What is the line below the ל?

Another example: קָדְשֶֽׁךָ

These marks seem like cantillation marks, however this is not a selection from the Tanach.

Comment: Where did you find these words. The three dots are a cantilation mark. The line shows where to put emphasis.

Comment: It's from the Al Hanissim

Comment: Can you be more specific. Where did you copy this from.

Comment: @robev Sefaria website

Comment: @Burt You should probably mention those things (along with a link to where you saw these examples) in the question itself.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based off your comments, I have concluded that the symbols you are seeing are helpful aids that have been put in the [Sefaria Siddur](https://www.sefaria.org/Siddur_Ashkenaz), apparently based on the Metsuda Siddur.

The three dots are to convey a "sheva na". That is, the sheva vowel is either a moving sheva (like the word "sheva"), or a resting sheva (like "ach"). The three dots conveys a moving sheva.

The straight line appears in most siddurim. It's called a meteg and conveys where to place emphasis when pronouncing a word. See [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteg).

Comment: Regarding the _Meteg_: It [usually] appears in words where the emphasis is not on the last sylabel/vowel